# Mongoose best way to store a set of ids in a document? Map? Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a table `Entries` where each document represents a list entry. Among other info, I want to store a set of `id`'s in each document. These `id`'s will be strings. The relevant `id`'s needed will vary between different documents. When these documents are retrieved, the goal is to be able to efficiently display the entries in a React table and filter by the `id`'s each document has, which seems like would make the most sense as a javascript `Set`.

Example of what I'm thinking of:

```
{
  name: "Bob",
  ids: {
    "1234a",
    "9999b"
  }
},
{
  name: "Paul",
  ids: {
    "9999b",
    "0000z"
  }
}
```

From reading around, it looks like I could potentially store `ids` as an `Array`, and convert them to a Set when retrieved.

Another options seems to be to store `ids` as a Map, where the key is the `id` and the value is something arbitrary (like `true` or something). Example:

```
{
  name: "Paul",
  ids: {
    "9999b": true,
    "0000z": true
  }
}
```

What would be the most performant way to do this?

Comment: {
  name: "Bob",
  ids: [
    "1234a",
    "9999b"
  ]
},
{
  name: "Paul",
  ids: [
    "9999b",
    "0000z"
  ]
}

Comment: Using any data values as fields/keys will only lead to future pain when you want to query the documents.  Always keep your queries in mind when designing your data model.

Comment: @rickhg12hs So would the most performant way be to store ids as an array, and then convert them to Set upon retrieval? 

Would this be a problem if I'm potentially retrieving hundreds or thousands at a time?

Comment: Make the MongoDB server do most of the work.  With the right aggregation pipeline, all the filtering/etc. can be done by the server and simplify your post-processing.  Filtering at the server will also reduce the amount of data returned and save a lot of network communication time.

Comment: mongodb query language is made to query easy an known schema, not data in fields, if you want to query those fields(not just retrieve them all unchanged) data on fields will cause problems and you would need to do complicated things like `ObjectToarray` You can save a normal array, and if you want you can make it map before retrieving them, with aggregation framework, for example with $map and `arrayToObject`